# Showing an Alert Dialog in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I want to giving an alert when there is an exception, like in code:

```
try
{
    //the code here
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //show an alert dialog here
}
```

An example or a code snippet is what I need.

Comment: See [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) tutorial

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` with `WARNING_MESSAGE` :

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(yourFrame,
    "WARNING.",
    "Warning",
    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

More infos about how to make dialogs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Comment: if you don't have access to frame at the moment, you can use null as a first argument

Answer (score 12):

try this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "My Goodness, this is so concise");
```

If you statically import JOptionPane.showMessageDialog this further reduces to

```
showMessageDialog(null, "This language just gets better and better!");
```

Comment: I think the second part of the answer is not needed, you can do this with almost every method, but in fact you shouldn't (see for example here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html, last paragraph).